# Excel to Sharepoint MapNetworkDrive error

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

Using Excel 2013, I'm trying to upload an excel file to sharepoint using the method below. I seem to be having an issue mapping my network drive, the error I get is "The specified device name is invalid" on the `objNet.MapNetworkDrive "A: ", sFolder` line.

Any help with the matter is appreciated- thanks in advance.

```
Sub nlsharepoint()

Dim sFolder As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim locFolder
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

sFolder =  "\\company.sharepoint.com\sites\company\Documents\Morning%20Reports\"
sFileName = "New Line Tracker 2.xlsx"
locFolder = "C:\User\Desktop\NewLinesOutput.xlsx"

Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objNet.MapNetworkDrive "A: ", sFolder

If FS.fileexists(locFolder) Then
FS.copyfile locFolder, sFolder
End If

objNet.RemoveNetworkDrive "A:"
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is right, but it seems to simple so if not let me know and I'll delete.

I believe that you need to replace this line:

```
objNet.MapNetworkDrive "A: ", sFolder
```

with this:

```
objNet.MapNetworkDrive "A:", sFolder
```

There's a space after you specify the drive to map, and I don't believe that there should be.

Comment: Thanks, that has effectively dealt with the "specified device name is invalid" error.  Unfortunately for me I get a "Network Path not found" error on the same line.  I find this odd as I can save to the location using the same string in another sub.  Assuming that all I have done to make the sFolder string anonymous is substitute my company name, does the formatting look right here?  Could you suggest anything else causing this error?

Comment: It's midnight here so I can't do any testing but what happens if you put the SPO path instead of a UNC one? Ie. Make sFolder =  "http://company.sharepoint.com/sites/company/Documents/Morning%20Reports/"

Comment: Using "company.sharepoint.com/company/Documents/Morning Reports" or "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/company/Documents/Morning Reports/" I get a Network Name cannot be found.

Thanks for the help at this late hour!